# How JAVA format date 4/06/2011 instead of 04/06/2011 use GregorianCalendar? String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tY", today);

Tags: java

How JAVA format date

> 4/06/2011

instead of 0

> 4/06/2011

?

I need to use GregorianCalendar

```
GregorianCalendar today=new GregorianCalendar();
String todayStr = String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tY", today);
```

gives

> 04/06/2011

I want

> 4/06/2011

thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't the month always be two digits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DateFormat dateFormat1=new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(dateFormat1.format(new Date()));
```

**Output:**

> 4/06/2011

**Note:** It might fail for month greater than Oct.

Comment: i need to use  GregorianCalendar today=new GregorianCalendar();
 String todayStr = String.format("%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tY", today);

Comment: @jenifer, If you cannot change it, why do you ask the question? What can you change?

Comment: @jenifer I think you need string representation of date with mentioned format, I have already answered for that.

Comment: @ Jigar Joshi you solution not works, because i need  GregorianCalendar datatype, not Date type

Comment: `GregorianCalendar` extends `Calendar` and it has got a method to get `Date` Object , use it `getTime()` , [For more info check java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html)

Comment: You are welcome :) , (also to mark it as answered as it is ;)  )

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using `String.format(...)`. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt), there is no such converter as month without leading zeros. You can either use the `DateFormat` or do it somehow manually (strip the leading zero from month if present).

Comment: that's why i ask, it seems dateFormat is a must

Comment: Yes, and the answer is: It is a must :)